# How to get post filedata in jQUERY

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, file-upload

I have a form with three post data along with that I have to append a filedata(input type="file"). I didn't get the filedata, when I alert the post data in js. How can I resolve it? please suggest a solution..

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0qdk.png
```

```js
    $('#employerid_contactus').click(function (event) {
    
            cs_data_loader_load('#cs_employer_contactus #loader-data');
            var default_message = jQuery("#cs_employer_contactus").data('validationmsg');
            event.preventDefault();
            var ajaxurl = jQuery(".cs-profile-contact-detail").data('adminurl');
            var employerid = jQuery(".profile-contact-btn").data('employerid');
    
            var captcha_id = jQuery(".cs-profile-contact-detail").data('cap');
    
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: ajaxurl,
                dataType: "html",
                data: $('#ajaxcontactemployer').serialize() + "&employerid=" + employerid + "&action=ajaxcontact_employer_send_mail",
                success: function (response) {
                    jQuery("#ajaxcontactemail").removeClass('has_error');
                    jQuery("#ajaxcontactname").removeClass('has_error');
                    jQuery("#ajaxcontactcontents").removeClass("has_error");
    
                    var pattern = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+\.([a-zA-Z])+([a-zA-Z])+/;
                    var response_data = response.split("|");
                    if (jQuery("#ajaxcontactname").val() == '') {
                        jQuery("#ajaxcontactname").addClass('has_error');
                    } else
                    if (!pattern.test(jQuery("#ajaxcontactemail").val())) {
                        jQuery("#ajaxcontactemail").addClass('has_error');
                    } else
                    if (jQuery("#ajaxcontactcontents").val().length < 35) {
                        jQuery("#ajaxcontactcontents").addClass('has_error');
                    }
                    var error_container = '';
                    if (response_data[1] == 1) {
                        error_container = '<div class="alert alert-danger"><button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="alert" type="button" class="close">×</button><p><i class="icon-warning4"></i>' + response_data[0] + '</p></div>';
                        jQuery("#ajaxcontact-response").html(error_container);
                    } else {
                        error_container = '<div class="alert success"><button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="alert" type="button" class="close">×</button><p><i class="icon-warning4"></i>' + response_data[0] + '</p></div>';
                        jQuery("#ajaxcontact-response").html(error_container);
                        jQuery("#ajaxcontactcontents").val('');
                        captcha_reload(ajaxurl, captcha_id);
                    }
    
                    jQuery('#cs_employer_contactus #loader-data').html('');
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
```

```html
    this is how form view code:
    
        
    
    <div class="input-filed"> <i class="icon-mobile4"></i>
       <?php
          $cs_opt_array = array(
              'id' => '',
              'std' => isset($login_user_phone) ? esc_html($login_user_phone) : '',
              'cust_id' => "ajaxcontactphone",
              'cust_name' => "ajaxcontactphone",
              'classes' => 'form-control',
              'extra_atr' => 'placeholder="' . esc_html__('Phone Number', 'jobhunt') . '"',
          );
          $cs_form_fields2->cs_form_text_render($cs_opt_array);
          ?>
    </div>
    <div class="input-filed"> <i class="icon-mobile4"></i>
       <?php
          $cs_opt_array = array(
              'id' => '',
              'std' => '',
              'cust_id' => "ajaxcontactfile",
              'cust_name' => "ajaxcontactfile",
              'cust_type' => "file",
              'classes' => 'form-control',
              'extra_atr' => '',
          );
          $cs_form_fields2->cs_form_text_render($cs_opt_array);
          ?>
    </div>
```

**When serialize the postdata I didn't get the filedata**
I need to send an email using ajax. I can send name, email and phone number but not the file. I need to include file along with these fields. When I alert the serialized data in js it not showing the filedata. How can I append the file with postdata. Please help me with this.

Comment: please show you code

Comment: if u upload file it should return filename uploaded on your server

Comment: send your code please

Comment: Had you set `enctype='multipart/form-data'` in your `<form>` tag?

Comment: Also try outputing your fields using `print_r($_POST) ;` and see if you are getting all the fields.

Comment: What do you want to do with that data on frontend?

Comment: `print_r($_FILES);` Have you tried this ?

Comment: Hi, 
I haven't include this "enctype='multipart/form-data' " @ David R

Comment: you should refer jquery form js http://malsup.com/jquery/form/